# Moduli stacks of algebraic surfaces—obstructions to existence?

Tags: moduli-spaces, stacks, algebraic-surfaces, algebraic-stacks

The moduli stack $\mathcal{M}_g$ of genus $g$ curves is one of the deepest objects in mathematics, so of course you wonder to what extent you can construct an (Artin?) stack parametrising algebraic *surfaces*.

Recall how to construct a moduli space $\mathcal{M}$ containing a curve $X$ using deformation theory (reference is Hartshorne's book):

1. *Representability*. To construct the formal neighbourhood $D_{\mathcal{M},X}$ of $X$ in $\mathcal{M}$, note that if $\text{Spec}A$ is a fat point (i.e. $A$ is Artinian) then maps into $\mathcal{M}$ correspond to flat families of schemes over $\text{Spec}A$ with central fibre $X$. Then use Artin representability to show (under conditions) that this functor
   $$F\ :\ \text{Artin rings} \ \to \ \text{Sets/Groupoids}$$
   sending
   $$A\ \mapsto\ \{\text{flat families of schemes over }\text{Spec}A \text{with central fibre }X\}$$
   is represented by a formal scheme/stack $D_{\mathcal{M},X}$.
2. *Algebraicity*. To construct an open neighbourhood of $X$, we need to show that $D_{\mathcal{M},X}$ can be “algebraised” to a scheme/stack $U_{\mathcal{M},X}$. This can be done using Artin algebraicity, under conditions. A stronger condition is that $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$.

**Question:** (*edit:* answered in [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424149/moduli-stacks-of-algebraic-surfaces-obstructions-to-existence#comment1090409_424149) below) Let $X$ be an algebraic surface. I have not seen a general definition of a moduli stack of algebraic surfaces containing $X$. So I assume either 1 or 2 does not work—which is it, and why?  If $F$ is not represented by the formal completion of some stack, is there no hope of building a moduli stack for $X$?

**tl;dr** what (if anything) fails when you try to use deformation theory to build a moduli stack of surfaces near $X$?

---

*Edit:*

**Edited question:** What is the obstruction to the existence of the *analytic* moduli stacks $\mathcal{M}$? Do they always exist?

---

There are other questions, e.g. [Results about moduli of surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191099/results-about-moduli-of-surfaces), but it is unclear how many problems there come from not working with stacks, and also it is unclear what is *expected* to be true.

Comment: What about K3 surfaces? The general deformation (in the Kodaira-Spencer sense) of an algebraic K3 is not algebraic, so you need some extra structure in order to build a moduli space in the algebraic category (for instance, you can fix a polarization).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A. Surely by construction the functor $F$ only sees the algebraic deformations? So in the K3 case $\dim F(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)-\dim F(k)=19$, not 20? I'm not sure what you mean by Kodaira-Spencer, but I'm definitely not looking at all deformations as complex manifolds. B. Are you claiming that in the K3 case $F$ is not representable by an Artin stack (or rather the formal neighbourhood of a point in an Artin stack)? I thought that one considers polarisations to make the resulting stacks DM, and not because 1 or 2 failed (which I think you are claiming?).

Comment: Pulcinella, you are wrong.

Comment: About what part?

Comment: A flat, locally finitely presented morphism of complex analytic spaces to Spec of a local Artin $\mathbb{C}$-algebra (with residue field equal to $\mathbb{C}$) is the morphism of complex analytic spaces associated to a flat, locally finitely presented morphism of schemes if and only if the base change to $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}$ is the complex analytic space associated to a finitely presented $\mathbb{C}$-scheme.  So there is no "intrinstic" way to distinguish "algebraic" infinitesimal deformations of K3 surfaces, Abelian varieties, etc., from the "analytic" infinitesimal deformations.

Comment: Thanks both very much, that was an embarrassing mistake by me. Your comments answer my question (for readers- https://mathoverflow.net/a/16000/119012 also seems relevant). 

As far as I can tell, you could ask my question in the analytic category- in that case, is the (obstruction to the) existence of an analytic moduli stack $\mathcal{M}$ well known? If not maybe I should edit my question to be about that.

Comment: The analytic stacks do exist.  This is probably due to Bingener and Buchweitz, but I need to double-check.

Comment: Did you manage to find a reference? I'd be happy to type up an answer based on a reference, but searching Bingener and Buchweitz didn't give anything for me.